# Checking a string contains only ASCII characters

Tags: go, ascii

Does Go have any method or there is a suggestion how to check if a string contains only ASCII characters? What is the right way to do it?

From my research, one of the solution is to check whatever there is any char greater than 127.

```
func isASCII(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: According to [go doc](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/) there is no such a way to do this, I think you did research well.

Comment: Looks good to me, ship it :thumbsup:

Comment: I believe an ASCII character is represented by a byte whereas the UTF-8 encoding of a non-ASCII character requires two or more bytes. I wonder if checking whether the number of bytes of a string is equal to its length is a reliable method to determine whether it contains ASCII only characters.

Comment: @daplho I think this can be done with `utf8.RuneCount(buf) == len(buf)`, but unsure about performance

Comment: @daphlo the only issue there is that bytes are in the range of `[0,0xff]` whereas ASCII characters are in `[0,0x7f]`; so even if the lengths are equal there could still be bytes with values outside of the valid range.

Comment: yeah @maerics, given this discussion it does look to me that the OP is really the most reliable and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Strange though it may seem, `utf8.RuneCount(buf) == len(buf)` is actually a valid implementation. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), code points above U+007F are encoded to 2 or more bytes in UTF-8, thus, if the RuneCount equals the length, the string must be pure ASCII.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Go, we care about performance, Therefore, we would benchmark your code:

```
func isASCII(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

BenchmarkRange-4    20000000    82.0 ns/op
```

A faster (better, more idiomatic) version, which avoids unnecessary rune conversions:

```
func isASCII(s string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

BenchmarkIndex-4    30000000    55.4 ns/op
```

---

`ascii_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "unicode"
)

func isASCIIRange(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func BenchmarkRange(b *testing.B) {
    str := ascii()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        is := isASCIIRange(str)
        if !is {
            b.Fatal("notASCII")
        }
    }
}

func isASCIIIndex(s string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func BenchmarkIndex(b *testing.B) {
    str := ascii()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        is := isASCIIIndex(str)
        if !is {
            b.Log("notASCII")
        }
    }
}

func ascii() string {
    byt := make([]byte, unicode.MaxASCII+1)
    for i := range byt {
        byt[i] = byte(i)
    }
    return string(byt)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test ascii_test.go -bench=.
BenchmarkRange-4    20000000    82.0 ns/op
BenchmarkIndex-4    30000000    55.4 ns/op
$
```

Comment: indexing with `string` is not corrent，`s[i]` is a `byte`, but  In `for _, c := range s {` , `c` is a rune.

Comment: This is indeed fast and correct code, but not as reusable as what the OP suggested. Specifically, this code can be used to check if the string contains of characters below `U+xxxx` only if `xxxx` is no more than (0x)0080; that is based on the backward compatibility of UTF-8 to ASCII (ref: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.17.2/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L17).

Comment: @alexli in this case it's OK as we're expecting ASCII which can be compared as bytes.

Comment: Regardless this is great answer, "in Go, we care about performance", actually we don't. This language doesn't intend to be performant and its not one of its design goals, it is actually pretty slow in many areas. If code that runs 55NS makes a difference from 82NS, then go is not the language you should write (for example, GC can stop the world for 500MS easily)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your way is best.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is simply defined as:

> ASCII encodes 128 specified characters into seven-bit integers

As such, characters have values 0-2<sup>7</sup> (or 0-127, 0x0-0x7F).

Go provides no way to check that every rune in a string (or byte in a slice) has numerical values in a specific range, so your code seems to be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/exp/utf8string"

func main() {
   {
      b := utf8string.NewString("south north").IsASCII()
      println(b) // true
   }
   {
      b := utf8string.NewString("").IsASCII()
      println(b) // false
   }
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/utf8string#String.IsASCII

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is faster than the original proposed asolution, but I'd argue the original proposed solution is more idiomatic.  The original solution is idiomatic because almost always, you're more interested in code points versus individual utf8 encoded byte values when you're looking through the contents of a string in go.  Range is 100% idiomatic here.

In this specific case, indexing the string and comparing bytes happens to be faster and still gives us a correct result.  But it's still not an optimized solution.  Not even close.

So let's build a bikeshed.

So for a non-idiomatic (though based on stdlib code) implementation that's way way faster, I present the following:

```
func isASCIIIndexBy8s32(s string) bool {
    // idea adapted from here:
    // https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go;l=528
    for len(s) > 0 {
        if len(s) >= 8 {
            first32 := uint32(s[0]) | uint32(s[1])<<8 | uint32(s[2])<<16 | uint32(s[3])<<24
            second32 := uint32(s[4]) | uint32(s[5])<<8 | uint32(s[6])<<16 | uint32(s[7])<<24
            if (first32|second32)&0x80808080 != 0 {
                return false
            }
            s = s[8:]
            continue
        }
        if s[0] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
        s = s[1:]
    }
    return true
}
```

This is over twice as fast as the indexing example.  And a further optimization for 64 bit cpus gives us another 20% improvement over that one.

Full code here.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "unicode"
)

func isASCIIRange(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isASCIIIndex(s string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isASCIIIndexBy8s32(s string) bool {
    // idea adapted from here:
    // https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go;l=528
    for len(s) > 0 {
        if len(s) >= 8 {
            first32 := uint32(s[0]) | uint32(s[1])<<8 | uint32(s[2])<<16 | uint32(s[3])<<24
            second32 := uint32(s[4]) | uint32(s[5])<<8 | uint32(s[6])<<16 | uint32(s[7])<<24
            if (first32|second32)&0x80808080 != 0 {
                return false
            }
            s = s[8:]
            continue
        }
        if s[0] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
        s = s[1:]
    }
    return true
}

func isASCIIIndexBy8s64(s string) bool {
    // optimizing the 32 bit example above for 64 bit cpus
    for len(s) > 0 {
        if len(s) >= 8 {
            chunk := uint64(s[0]) | uint64(s[1])<<8 | uint64(s[2])<<16 | uint64(s[3])<<24 |
                uint64(s[4])<<32 | uint64(s[5])<<40 | uint64(s[6])<<48 | uint64(s[7])<<56
            if chunk&0x8080808080808080 != 0 {
                return false
            }
            s = s[8:]
            continue
        }
        if s[0] > unicode.MaxASCII {
            return false
        }
        s = s[1:]
    }
    return true
}

var tests = []struct {
    n string
    f func(string) bool
}{
    {
        n: "range",
        f: isASCIIRange,
    }, {
        n: "index",
        f: isASCIIIndex,
    }, {
        n: "index 8 32",
        f: isASCIIIndexBy8s32,
    }, {
        n: "index 8 64",
        f: isASCIIIndexBy8s64,
    },
}

func TestAsciis(t *testing.T) {
    atxt := "this is ascii text"
    utxt := "this is some unicode and a lot more ascii text afterwards"
    for _, tst := range tests {
        t.Run(tst.n, func(t *testing.T) {
            if !tst.f(atxt) {
                t.Errorf("%s failed for %s", tst.n, atxt)
            }
            if tst.f(utxt) {
                t.Errorf("%s failed for %s", tst.n, utxt)
            }
        })
    }
}

func BenchmarkAsciis(b *testing.B) {
    str := ascii()
    for _, bnch := range tests {
        b.Run(bnch.n, func(b *testing.B) {
            b.ResetTimer()
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                if !bnch.f(str) {
                    b.Errorf("not ascii")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func ascii() string {
    byt := make([]byte, unicode.MaxASCII+1)
    for i := range byt {
        byt[i] = byte(i)
    }
    return string(byt)
}
```

Running this gives:

```
=== RUN   TestAsciis
=== RUN   TestAsciis/range
=== RUN   TestAsciis/index
=== RUN   TestAsciis/index_8_32
=== RUN   TestAsciis/index_8_64
--- PASS: TestAsciis (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestAsciis/range (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestAsciis/index (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestAsciis/index_8_32 (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestAsciis/index_8_64 (0.00s)
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: playground
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1068NG7 CPU @ 2.30GHz
BenchmarkAsciis
BenchmarkAsciis/range
BenchmarkAsciis/range-8             13469913            86.72 ns/op
BenchmarkAsciis/index
BenchmarkAsciis/index-8             24108583            49.56 ns/op
BenchmarkAsciis/index_8_32
BenchmarkAsciis/index_8_32-8        62092825            20.89 ns/op
BenchmarkAsciis/index_8_64
BenchmarkAsciis/index_8_64-8        77044797            15.91 ns/op
PASS
```